# Unity inbuilt function CharacterController.Move not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to implement a dash/teleport function where the player moves forward a short distance when left shift is pressed. The CharacterController.Move() function isn't having any effect on the player. I've tried it with hardcoding different directions and speeds and that doesn't have any difference. The same function is working elsewhere in the code, just not inside my teleport script, and I don't know why.

Script attached below.

```
using Unity.FPS.Game;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

namespace Unity.FPS.Gameplay
{

    public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour // Set up function for teleporting
    {

        // Initialise variables
        PlayerCharacterController m_PlayerCharacterController;
        PlayerInputHandler m_InputHandler;
        public bool IsPlayergrounded() => m_PlayerCharacterController.IsGrounded;
        public bool canUseTeleport;
        public bool teleporting;
        CharacterController m_Controller;
        public Vector3 TeleportDirection { get; set; }
        public int TeleportSpeed;

        void Start()
        {
            print("The teleport function was called");

            // Get variable values
            m_PlayerCharacterController = GetComponent<PlayerCharacterController>();
            m_InputHandler = GetComponent<PlayerInputHandler>();
            m_Controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            TeleportDirection = m_Controller.velocity;
            TeleportSpeed = 2;
            canUseTeleport = true;

        }

        void Update()
        {

            // teleport can only be used if not grounded
            if (IsPlayergrounded())
            {
                teleporting = false;
                canUseTeleport = true; // reset teleport when landed
            }
            else if (!m_PlayerCharacterController.HasJumpedThisFrame && m_InputHandler.GetTeleportInputDown() && canUseTeleport)
            {
                teleporting = true;
            }

            if (teleporting)
            {
                // add teleport speed boost
                m_PlayerCharacterController.stackedSpeedBoosts += 1;
                if (m_PlayerCharacterController.stackedSpeedBoosts > m_PlayerCharacterController.stackLimit)
                {
                    m_PlayerCharacterController.stackedSpeedBoosts = m_PlayerCharacterController.stackLimit;
                }

                // use the player's velocity to calculate the teleport direction
                TeleportDirection = m_Controller.velocity;

                // change player's coordinates TODO make this work
                m_Controller.Move(TeleportDirection * Time.deltaTime * TeleportSpeed);

                // increase player's speed after teleporting
                m_PlayerCharacterController.TeleportBoost = true;

                // can only teleport once before hitting the ground
                canUseTeleport = false;
                teleporting = false;

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `Debug.Log` code work under the `m_Controller.Move(TeleportDirection * Time.deltaTime * TeleportSpeed)`;
 code?

Comment: Yep, I tried it just now and it can reach that line of code

Comment: `TeleportDirection = m_Controller.velocity` is zero at start, it will affect on result.

Comment: It's zero at start yes, but it also gets updated before the move function is used

Comment: how velocity can update when controller cant move? the velocity return automatically the controller's output vector. To solve the problem make the `TeleportDirection` independent of `controller.velocity`. I suggest using transform.forward or similar.

Comment: The velocity is being updated in another script. I tried printing it and it wasn't staying at zero

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! Apparently the move function gets broken if you try to use it more than once per frame. So instead of using the move function in my teleport script, I'm now only using the teleport script to change velocity and am then combining all my movement info together in one main movement script that runs the CharacterController.Move function.